# Three.js - how can I get rid of the flashing red lights on my objects

Tags: three.js

I'm new to using Three.js and am using this to learn so hopefully this isn't a ridiculous question.

I have a weird transition red color on my mesh objects which is turning the images/texture a red color but I have no idea where it's coming from. I've tried moving the camera angle, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

This is the code:

```
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/FirstPersonControls.js"></script>

    <script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>

    <script>

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container;
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        var light, pointLight;

        var mesh, mesh1, mesh2, mesh3, mesh4, mesh5;
        var material_sphere1, material_sphere2, material_sphere3, material_sphere4, material_sphere5;

        var clock = new THREE.Clock();

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 500 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 25, 0 );

            var listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
            camera.add( listener );

            controls = new THREE.FirstPersonControls( camera );

            controls.movementSpeed = 160;
            controls.lookSpeed = 0.08;
            controls.noFly = true;
            controls.lookVertical = false;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();


var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'http://tam.outbrain.com/anita/vr-module-rec-by-nytimes.png', {}, function(){ 
// use to test when image gets loaded if it does
// alert('texture loaded') 
}, 
function(){ 
    alert('error') 
});

var texture2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'http://tam.outbrain.com/anita/vr-module-rec-by-snl.png', {}, function(){ 
// use to test when image gets loaded if it does
// alert('texture loaded') 
}, 
function(){ 
    alert('error') 
});

var texture3 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'http://tam.outbrain.com/anita/vr-module-rec-by-toms.png', {}, function(){ 
// use to test when image gets loaded if it does
// alert('texture loaded') 
}, 
function(){ 
    alert('error') 
});

var texture4 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'http://tam.outbrain.com/anita/vr-module-rec-by-verse.png', {}, function(){ 
// use to test when image gets loaded if it does
// alert('texture loaded') 
}, 
function(){ 
    alert('error') 
});

var texture5 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'http://tam.outbrain.com/anita/vr-module-rec-by-whats-happening.png', {}, function(){ 
// use to test when image gets loaded if it does
// alert('texture loaded') 
}, 
function(){ 
    alert('error') 
});




            var sphere = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 30, 30 );
            var sphere2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 30, 30 );
            var sphere3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 30, 30 );
            var sphere4 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 30, 30 );
            var sphere5 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 30, 30 );


            material_sphere1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, color: 0x000000} );
            material_sphere2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2, color: 0x000000} );
            material_sphere3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture3, color: 0x000000} );
            material_sphere4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture4, color: 0x000000} );
            material_sphere5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture5, color: 0x000000} );



            // sound spheres

            var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material_sphere1 );
            mesh1.position.set( 42, 25, 0 );
            scene.add( mesh1 );


            //

            var mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( sphere2, material_sphere2 );
            mesh2.position.set( 30, 25, 35 );
            mesh2.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 4;
            scene.add( mesh2 );

            //
            var mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh( sphere3, material_sphere3 );
            mesh3.position.set( -5, 25, 50 );
            mesh3.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 2;
            scene.add( mesh3 );


            //
            var mesh4 = new THREE.Mesh( sphere4, material_sphere4 );
            mesh4.position.set( 30, 25, -35 );
            mesh4.rotation.y = -Math.PI / -4;
            scene.add( mesh4 );


            //
            var mesh5 = new THREE.Mesh( sphere5, material_sphere5 );
            mesh5.position.set( -5, 25, -50 );
            mesh5.rotation.y = -Math.PI / -2;
            scene.add( mesh5 );






            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.innerHTML = "";
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            controls.handleResize();

        }

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();

        }


        function render() {

            var delta = clock.getDelta(),
                time = clock.getElapsedTime() * 5;

            controls.update( delta );

            material_sphere1.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
            material_sphere2.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
            material_sphere3.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
            material_sphere4.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
            material_sphere5.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );



            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these rows in the `render` method:

```
        material_sphere1.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
        material_sphere2.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
        material_sphere3.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
        material_sphere4.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
        material_sphere5.color.setHSL( 0.0, 0.3 + 0.7 * ( 1 + Math.cos( time ) ) / 2, 0.5 );
```

you need to remove them in order to remove red flashing.

But then you will not see your images at all as you basic materials are black. So you need to change your materials color from `0x000000` to `0xFFFFFF` in materials creation:

```
        material_sphere1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, color: 0xFFFFFF} );
        material_sphere2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2, color: 0xFFFFFF} );
        material_sphere3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture3, color: 0xFFFFFF} );
        material_sphere4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture4, color: 0xFFFFFF} );
        material_sphere5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture5, color: 0xFFFFFF} );
```

Comment: Thanks, I JUST figured that out. I didn't realize it would cause such a problem. I appreciate the answer!